# Problem with the Inverse CDF of Non-central F Ratio Distribution

Tags: numerics, probability-or-statistics, precision-and-accuracy

```
In[3]:= n = 5; n1 = 4; n2 = 6; γ = 0.05; α = 1/370;
InverseCDF[NoncentralFRatioDistribution[1, n1 - 1, n1/γ^2], 
 1 - α - (n - n1)/n2]
```

> During evaluation of In[3]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search
>   decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal
>   and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the
>   merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of
>   working precision to meet these tolerances. >>

```
Out[4]= 3.24659
```

The correct answer is 5468.146427955789

Answer (score 6):

Use [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) directly with arbitrary-precision

```
n = 5; n1 = 4; n2 = 6; γ = 1/20; α = 1/370;

icdf = x /. 
  FindRoot[CDF[NoncentralFRatioDistribution[1, n1 - 1, n1/γ^2], x] == 
    1 - α - (n - n1)/n2, {x, 500}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]

(* 5468.146403807255 *)
```

Verifying,

```
(CDF[NoncentralFRatioDistribution[1, n1 - 1, n1/γ^2], icdf] // 
   RootApproximant) === 1 - α - (n - n1)/n2

(* True *)
```

Note that while the starting value used in `FindRoot` needs to be large, it does not have to be particularly close to the actual value.

**EDIT:** To "correct" the `InverseCDF` define your own function

```
Clear["Global`*"]

n = 5; n1 = 4; n2 = 6; γ = 1/20; α = 1/370;

invCDF[dist_, q_, start_: 50, wkprec_: $MachinePrecision] :=
 Module[
  {x, distr = Rationalize[dist], qr = Rationalize[q]},
  Check[InverseCDF[dist, q],
   x /. FindRoot[CDF[distr, x] == qr, {x, start},
     WorkingPrecision -> wkprec]]]

dist = NoncentralFRatioDistribution[1, n1 - 1, n1/γ^2];
```

Exact input to `invCDF` will output exact output (i.e., unevaluated for your example distribution). Since `InverseCDF` does not throw an error message, switching to `FindRoot` does not occur.

```
invCDF[dist, 1 - α - (n - n1)/n2]

(* InverseCDF[NoncentralFRatioDistribution[1, 3, 1600], 461/555] *)
```

This is desired for less complicated distributions for which the `InverseCDF` is known, e.g.,

```
invCDF[NormalDistribution[], 3/4]

(* Sqrt[2] InverseErfc[1/2] *)
```

Converting the argument for your distribution to a numeric approximation will result in evaluation and the desired switching to `FindRoot`.

```
invCDF[dist, 1 - α - (n - n1)/n2 // N] // Quiet

(* 5468.146403807255 *)
```

Comment: See edit for "corrected" function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. The problem is you have fixed the starting value at 50 in the findroot function, which will not be the good choice in general. The starting value maybe 0.5. It means, every time we need to put the correct starting value. The built-in inverseCDF function, however, doesn't require any starting value. The problem is thus still there!!

Comment: The starting value is **not** fixed at `50` it defaults to `50`. You can specify any starting value that you want. The default used by `InverseCDF` isn't working so I gave you the ability to specify one.